# PDF parsing library compatible with .NET Core

Tags: library, pdf, .net

I'm looking to parse some PDF (extract paragraph from them). I used `iTextSharp` in the past, but it doesn't support .NET Core.

I also tried this lib: https://github.com/VahidN/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core
but the text extraction doesn't work very nicely. It just writes random words, not in the correct order, with a lot of incorrect symbols, really not usable.

Comment: PDF parsing is incredibly difficult, because of (some of the many) ways a PDF can encode text. Like not actually encoding the space character, and just having each word (or character) be positioned. I would suggest that PDF parsing is AI-complete (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete)

Answer (score 0):

[Essential PDF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) can be used to load PDFs and extract content from them.[.NET Core](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf#feature-matrix) is also supported.

```
//Load an existing PDF.
PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument(fileName);
//Load the first page.
PdfPageBase page = loadedDocument.Pages[0];
//Extract text from first page.
string extractedText = page.ExtractText();
//Close the document
loadedDocument.Close(true);
```

The entire product is available for free with no limitations through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: I dont earn more than a million, so I should be able to benefit from it. I will test this this evening, thank you

Comment: Can I get it from a Nuget package? If not, what DLL should I include to get this `PdfLoadedDocument`DLL?

Comment: @J4N: Yes. [Nuget feed](http://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_aspnetcore/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/aspnetcore) for .NET Core. The DLLs needed are Syncfusion.Compression.Portable.dll and Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable.dll

Comment: It seems that I don't have an `ExtractText`method on the `PdfPageBase`? What am I missing?

Comment: @J4N: I will check with the developers and get back to you.

Comment: That would be great, you are kind of my last ressort

Comment: Any update? I would really need to be able to use it.

Comment: @J4N: For some reason the method ins't included in the .NET Core version - I have asked the developers to add it and also asked for any workarounds. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @J4N: Can you please create a support ticket in the Syncfusion [support portal](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/) and provide a sample PDF document and the text that you are trying to extract. I am working with the developers to get the functionality ported as soon as possible and have additional details will help. Thanks.

Comment: But what would be the timeframe? I mean, if it's in 2 weeks, it's kind of useless... The pdf is located here: http://www.20min.ch/printpdf/VD_20170427.pdf And I'm trying to extract the horoscope(page 18), and I'm trying to extract the text and the number of stars for each astrological sign.

Comment: @J4N Thanks. This will help narrow down the solution. I understand the time constraint and will try to get this done ASAP.

Comment: @J4N The developers have promised a patch and working sample application by May 3, 2017. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: That would be awesome!

Comment: @J4N We have implemented the ExtractText functionality in PDF library in ASP.NET Core platform. The ExtractText method of the PDF library is supported from .NET Standard 1.3 version due to constraints in encoding. 
  
[Patched assemblies](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/177819/ze/Assemblies1562224339)
  
[Sample code](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/177819/ze/ExtractText_-849914005)

Comment: Good news, is this new version available with the NuGet package?

Comment: @J4N No. The changes are only in the assemblies attached here. The changes will make it into Nuget after the next release.

Comment: Are those supposed to work with a .NetCoreApp 1.1 ? For now I'm unable to reference them.

Comment: [Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/177819/ze/ExtractText1779853696) for ExtractText functionality with version .NETCoreApp 1.1
  
We have also generated [NuGet packages](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/177819/ze/packages-124819777) for "Syncfusion.Compression.Portable" and "Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable" in .NETStandard 1.3 version.

Comment: I opened your sample in VS2017, hit the compile button, and it says there is no ExtractText in PdfPaggeBase. Not sure what to do with a nuget package not coming from a nugget repo.

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/extension/syncfusion-nuget-packages/nuget-install-and-configuration#configure-the-syncfusion-nuget-packages-in-visual-studio-from-downloaded-packages) for using Nuget packages from the ZIP files.

Comment: I finally had the time to use your sample with your example, but when I try it, the "Sample.txt" contains only new lines. I did go to Debug to check and the ExtractText returns only some "\n"

Comment: We are unable to reproduce the issue with the PDF document provided earlier. Sample for text extraction with the latest NuGet packages(version 15.4140.0.17 [link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/177819/ze/ExtractText_sample309516714)

Please try with this and let me know.

Comment: I cannot open this project on VS2017: `C:\Users\jgro\Desktop\ExtractText_webApp\src\ExtractText_webApp\ExtractText_webApp.xproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Users\jgro\Desktop\ExtractText_webApp\src\ExtractText_webApp\ExtractText_webApp.xproj`

Comment: Earlier sample was created with VS 2015. We have created the sample for text extraction in VS 2017. [link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ExtractText-2014902038)

Comment: I just checked, now it seems to work! I'm just curious, the unicode symbols seems to be decoded as "uni2605" or "uni2729", this is a different behavior than the iTextSharp lib, is that expected ?

Comment: We extract text from the PDF document by mapping character ID to Character/difference map table value and get the Unicode values. We convert the Unicode value to characters, but we missed to handle it for hexadecimal values considering the encoding. If we convert the values by considering encoding used in the font resource dictionary then we get the expected characters. We will fix this issue and provide the patch on December 8, 2017.

Comment: You're awesome ! Thank you! Will this be available through a Nuget package update?

Comment: We have provided the patch as [NuGet package](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SynfusionNuGet_15.4.0.17-1045054535) as you have requested.

Comment: Hi, I'm in the processing of using your update, but: 
1) Is the zip you gave me working with .Net Core 2.0? Not sure with its naming
2) Did you also update your repository with this nugget? Because when I update my nugget package coming from your nugget repo, I still got the same issue.
3) In my latest tests, I did notice I've a lot unwanted "space" and sometimes even underscore, is there something I can do to reduce this?

Comment: We have fixed the Null Reference Exception in the text extraction and this will work in .NET Core 2.0 application. [Nuget patch](http://syncfusion.com/Installs/support/patch/15.4.0.20/16/177819/SyncfusionNuget_15.4.0.20_16_1032018072854024_177819.zip)
 
This fix will be included in our 2018 Volume 1 release (February 2018) and published to Nuget.

Comment: We are still working on the space and underscore character issue.

Comment: That would be awesome if you can fix it for the february 2018 release, because this character issue prevent me from doing some regular expression.

Comment: Do you have some update on this?

Comment: @j4n Release scheduled for February 16, 2018.

Comment: @j4n The release is done and the assemblies are in nuget

Comment: Awesome, I will test all this during this weekend!

Comment: I tried, but it appears that the extracted text has absolutely no spaces in it. Is there a way to tune this a little bit?

Comment: @J4N We are able to spaces in the test document you had provided earlier. Are you testing with a different document now? Could you please share that.

Comment: Yes I was able too, but I took a more recent version of the newspaper, and now I don't know why, it seems not able to retrieve the PDF. If you go here: https://epaper.20minuten.ch/?locale=fr#read/648/Lausanne/2018-03-08/1 Click on "Télécharger", then "Edition complète", you can get the document I used.

Answer (score 0):

[XFINIUM.PDF](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html) library supports text extraction on .NET Core platform.

```
// Load the PDF document
PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument(input);
// Create a content extractor for the desired page
PdfContentExtractor ce = new PdfContentExtractor(document.Pages[0]);
// Extract text as objects with information about position, font, color, etc
PdfTextFragmentCollection tfc = ce.ExtractTextFragments();
// Or extract the text as a simple string.
string text = ce.ExtractText();
```

Evaluation version is available for download on [nuget.org](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Xfinium.Pdf.NetCore/), package id is xfinium.pdf.netcore.

Disclaimer: I work for the company the develops [XFINIUM.PDF](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-overview.html) library.

Comment: Thank you, but it's for a free, very small and open source project, and I cannot afford this kind of fees

Answer (score 0):

[PdfLib CORE](https://github.com/jbaarssen/PdfLibCore) is a library for modern .NET Core applications to edit and read PDF files.

Snippet from the readme.md:

```
var dpiX, dpiY = 300D;
var i = 0;

using var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(File.Open(<<file>>, FileMode.Open));
foreach (var page in pdfDocument.Pages)
{
    using var pdfPage = page;
    var pageWidth = (int) (dpiX * pdfPage.Size.Width / 72);
    var pageHeight = (int) (dpiY * pdfPage.Size.Height / 72);

    using var bitmap = new PdfiumBitmap(pageWidth, pageHeight, true);
    pdfPage.Render(bitmap, PageOrientations.Normal, RenderingFlags.LcdText);
    using var stream = bitmap.AsBmpStream(dpiX, dpiY);
    
    // <<< do something with your stream...>>> 
}
```